# What does the "X" in MEXT(“Ministry of Education, Culture, Sports, Science and Technology/Monbukagakusho) stand for?

Tags: abbreviations

If the "X" stands for Culture, Sports and Science, why is it so?

Comment: MECSST sounds like “mext”. Nothing to do with the Japanese Language. (https://www.mext.go.jp/list_001/list_016/__icsFiles/afieldfile/2010/09/08/mext_2010_e.pdf ... `MEXT is the acronym of “Ministry of Education, Culture, Sports, Science and Technology” taken from the its abbreviation MECSST.`)